# RavenDB batch update

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb, batch-processing, batch-updates

I'm trying to perform batch update for the list of raven documents. The code below

```
var result =
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.Batch(documents.Select(d =>
  new PutCommandData
  {
    Document = RavenJObject.FromObject(d), 
    Etag = null, 
    Key = d.Id, 
    Metadata = new RavenJObject(),
  }).OfType<ICommandData>());
```

Although there are no exceptions and batch result contains correct update timestamp,
none of the documents updated in raven.

Tried to perform defer put command over a session with the same result.

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour? It seems that I'm missing something with batch updates.

Would appreciate any help and concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably writing to the system database, instead of the one you want.

```
documentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase("db-name")
```

Comment: Hi Ayende, I tried use explicit database reference you suggested, but with no effect. Still documents not updated in raven.

Comment: The problem was with wrong document keys. Found this in the database logs. Thanks for the answer, Ayende.